# Is there a way to update Storage and Resource Quota for an existing SharePoint Online site using CSOM C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I am using SharePoint CSOM with managed C# code to perform some automation on our SharePoint Online platform. Is there a way to update the storage and resource quota for an existing site collection using CSOM ? I know this can be achieved using PowerShell but I am looking for a solution using C#.

Thanks

Comment: Resource points are sort of useless now because they relate to sandbox code, which is being removed from the platform.